# react native app crash without any error on log

Tags: reactjs, react-native, crash

Run application then sometime later app crash without any error on log.

I'm use following but not display reason.

```
(1) chrome web browser console.
(2) adb logcat  
(3) react-native log-android
```

How can i trace crash?
is it possible of app use more memory so it is crash?
What is reason for crash without error log?

Comment: What error you are getting onto Red Screen?

Comment: not display any error

Comment: Did you get red screen while debug?

Comment: No it is Direct crash without red screen.

Comment: Are you debugging app or you have installed apk file directly?

Comment: i was try both 1)direct install apk file 2)react-native run-android deviceId=XXXXXXX

Comment: I have same problem did you find the solution